# Storing keys of inconsistent levels of dictionary

Tags: python, design-patterns

The structure of the code is like:

```
def foo(dicc, cases):
    if cases==1:
        return dicc['a']
    if cases==2:
        return dicc['b']['c']
```

`dicc` is not changeable. I want to eliminate the switch-like usage of `cases`. I thought about creating a dictionary outside the function like `info={1:'a',2:'b'}` and call like `dicc[info[cases]]`, but it won't work for case 2. Does this mean I have to create a class for each case? What is the common practice to deal with the problem?

Comment: it should be moved to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can try this

```
info=[['a'], ['b', 'c']]

def foo(dicc, cases):
    result = dicc
    for k in info[cases-1]:
        result = result[k]
    return result
```